# Can you set a new feeds user to take charge of more than one feed?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, feed

On [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge), we have... a [fair number of Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge?tab=feeds). Some of them serve similar purposes - we have a few devoted towards Gaming questions, some devoted towards general Stack Exchange material, and some devoted towards game questions on other SE sites.

In something of a reorganization effort, [our newest ♦ badp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp) ♪ is trying to reorganize the Feeds so that instead of everything coming from one Feeds user, separate categories come out from different users. Well, more accurately, all of the Gaming stuff is on one user and everything else on normal Feeds.

But the options seem to only be "Create New User", "Remove", and "Edit", none of which actually allow you to actually set the user. So if we wanted to change from Feeds, we'd need to create an entirely separate user for each one. Which doesn't quite mesh with the original plan of ease.

Is there a way to specifically assign an existing Feeds user to a feed? And if not, can we have this functionality added?

Comment: I remember talking about this in-chat with one of the developers (no, I don't remember who, but they are not that many) when the system was brand new... he said they'd think about it... he either lied or they're still thinking about it

Comment: Your ideas intrigue me and I would like to subscribe to your newsletter.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, I can apply that *manually* - there is no existing UI to do that. But I guess it wouldn't *really* allow anything too harmful if we added it...

Comment: Yes, please. We'd like that on [scifi.se], where we want the chatroom to feed several tags from [literature.se] and [movies.se]. It's a bit annoying to have to create one user per tag in order to have a different avatar per site.