# We need Captain Obvious back

Tags: support, chat, feed

Almost one month ago the new-question-feed of our main chat-room [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) posted by the special user named [Captain Obvious](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-263/captain-obvious) stopped working.

There had been a short discussion

> Room owner 1: 
>   I was more thinking along the lines of, would it help to remove/add the feed again?
>   Room owner 2: you can try for sure

which unfortunately resulted in  "[**Today is the day I killed Captain Obvious. Great. Just, great.**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47484173#47484173)"

After digging arround here on Meta I found this post [Can you set a new feeds user to take charge of more than one feed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79510/can-you-set-a-new-feeds-user-to-take-charge-of-more-than-one-feed) where the op asked

> "Is there a way to specifically assign an existing Feeds user to a feed? "

but unfortunately the answer from [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) had been

> "At the moment, I can apply that manually - there is no existing UI to do that. But I guess it wouldn't really allow anything too harmful if we added it..."

So we can't change the user of the new-question-feed back to [Captain Obvious](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-263/captain-obvious) by ourself. Could someone please do this for us?

Comment: I wholly support any attempt at reviving Captain Obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I can't do is assign the feed back to user -263, the "original" Captain Obvious.

What I *can* do is create a new feeds user, -786, and copy Captain Obvious' name and avatar across to it.

So I've done it.